# Groovy - How to trim spaces for each element in an array

Tags: groovy

I need to remove spaces from the value of City --
Here is the JSON-

```
{
  "School" : New Elementary School,
  "District" : "District1",
  "City" : "NewTown",
     "Students" : [ {
     "Name": "Student1",
     "Grade": "1"  
     "City":"     ABC"  
    }, {
     "Name": "Student2",
     "Grade": "2"
     "City":"     DEF"
    }, {
     "Name": "Student3",
     "Grade": "1"  
     "City":"     GHI"
    }, {
     "Name": "Student4",
     "Grade": "1"  
     "City":"     JKL"
    }, {
     "Name": "Student5",
     "Grade": "1"   
     "City":"     MNO"
    } ],
}
```

I tried using trim () by iterating on the Array. But the space still exists.

```
 def ArraySize = jsonIn."Students"."Row Set"[0].size()
 for(int i=0; i <= ArraySize ; i++)
 {
  jsonIn."Students"[0]."City"[i] = jsonIn."Students"[0]."City"[i].trim()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since after reading the data as json, you already have an copy, you can just reach into the structure and change it in place.  So your for was already in the right direction.  Iterate each `Student` and then replace the `City` in-place:

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("""{ "School" : "New Elementary School", "District" : "District1", "City" : "NewTown", "Students" : [ { "Name": "Student1", "Grade": "1", "City":" ABC" }, { "Name": "Student2", "Grade": "2", "City":" DEF" }, { "Name": "Student3", "Grade": "1", "City": " GHI" }, { "Name": "Student4", "Grade": "1", "City": " JKL" }, { "Name": "Student5", "Grade": "1", "City":" MNO" } ], }""")

data.Students.each{
    it.City = it.City.trim()
}

assert data.Students*.City == ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']
```